# I am trying to replace data within a specific set of rows in a specific column with NaN using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset, url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'

And I am trying to replace rows 10 to 17 with 'NaN'.

Here is my code:

```
iris['petal_length'] = iris['petal_length'].between(10,17).replace('NaN')
iris.iloc[10:18]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We can use loc

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[10:18,'petal length (cm)'] = np.nan
print(df.loc[10:18])
```

Ouput:

```
sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
5.4               3.7                NaN               0.2
4.8               3.4                NaN               0.2
4.8               3.0                NaN               0.1
4.3               3.0                NaN               0.1
5.8               4.0                NaN               0.2
5.7               4.4                NaN               0.4
5.4               3.9                NaN               0.4
5.1               3.5                NaN               0.3
5.7               3.8                NaN               0.3
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek! Much appreciated. I had to change a few things (reference to datafram) but the overall syntax worked a treat.